# Python equivalent to dplyr's summarize

Tags: r, python-3.x, group-by, summarize

Does there exist a `summarize` function in python like there is in R?!

I was going over the frequent itemset algo apriori and was looking for an a good dataset. I found one [here](https://www.kaggle.com/msp48731/frequent-itemsets-and-association-rules/code)

I can kind of read and understand R but do not know if a `summarize` function exists in Python :

In R this notebook has :

```
order_baskets <- ordr_pr %>% 
  inner_join(prods, by="product_id") %>% 
  group_by(order_id) %>%
  summarise(basket = as.vector(list(product_name)))
```

In python I would just :

```
pd.merge(ordr_pr, prods, how='inner', on='product_id')
 .groupby(order_id)
  # summarize( basket = as.vector(list(product_name)))
```

After the merge I am kind of lost, I am not even sure if the `groupby` does the same thing in python as it does in R.

Comment: the function is `agg` or `aggregate`

Comment: @RonakShah that fuction you mentioned is the `summary` function and not the `summarize` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `aggregate` or the `agg` function. thus you could have:

```
pd.merge(ordr_pr, prods, how='inner', on='product_id').groupby(order_id).agg({'product_name':list})
```